# Google APIs for Android is missing Games.getGamesAuthToken

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-api-client

The online [reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/Games#nested-class-summary) for *Google APIs for Android*, shows a public method summary for the **Games** class which includes:

```
static PendingResult<Games.GetTokenResult> getGamesAuthToken(GoogleApiClient apiClient)
```

But the latest release available (8.4.0) does not include this method. I use this to get the APIs:

```
dependencies {    
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
}
```

Where is Games.getGamesAuthToken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a documentation problem.  getGamesAuthToken() has been removed because it was not as secure as it needs to be.

For reference, you can read http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/01/play-games-permissions-are-changing-in.html

The best way to handle this is to:

After the player is authenticated on the device:

1. Get an auth code to send to your backend server:

   `GetServerAuthCodeResult result =
   Games.getGamesServerAuthCode(gac, clientId).await();
   if (result.isSuccess()) {
       String authCode = result.getCode(); 
           // Send code to server.
   }`
2. On the server, exchange the auth code received for a token by 
   making an RPC to `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` to exchange the auth code for an access token.
   You’ll have to provide the server client ID, server client secret (listed in the Developer Console when you created the server client ID), and the auth code.
   See more details here: [https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer?utm_campaign=play games_discussion_permissions_012316&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#handlingresponse](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer?utm_campaign=play%20games_discussion_permissions_012316&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#handlingresponse).
3. Once you have the access token, the player's ID is retrieved using:
   `www.googleapis.com/games/v1/applications/<app_id>/verify/` using the access token.
   Pass the auth token in a header as follows:
   “Authorization: OAuth ”

   The response value will contain the player ID for the user. This is the correct player ID to use for this user.
   This access token can be used to make additional server-to-server calls as needed.

Comment: Thanks @Clayton. The problem I see though is that .getGamesServerAuthCode is also shown as deprecated, which means that Google seems to be offering no accepted solution at all. Thoughts?

Comment: As far as I know, it is deprecated until the new permissions model is completely rolled out - which should be completed in the next few weeks (or so).  After that it will be a normal API.

Comment: I notice it is still deprecated.  Any word on this?

Comment: You should use GetServerAuthCode() - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount#getServerAuthCode()  For use see https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access

Comment: Sorry to bug you, but is it possible to do this without signing into any part of Google other than Games?  I've been using the gameHelper example to sign in and then doing a getGamesServerAuthCode after it signs in to pass a code to my server.  It seems to work, despite the deprecation.  Another question I've been dying to know is how I would get a server auth code from a java application that is non android

Comment: I tried using GetServerAuthCode() but I either wind up with "Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API cannot be used with Games.API" if I try to incorporate it with the Games sign in, or message about the games service not being connected if I leave them separate.

Comment: @ClaytonWilkinson Can you please let us know what is the correct way now? We see two ways listed one is showing as deprecated and other needs a different signin process (GetServerAuthCode) which may need significant changes in the code.

Comment: @ClaytonWilkinson The steps you described do not work - is there any actual solution to using Google Play Games login + server authentication? I do not want to implement standard login.